Splicing UF-B 6/3?
We’ve relocated our shop further back on the property and while pricing wire it was suggested that I “splice” my current UF-B 6/3 with new UF-B 6/3. Can that be done?

This question is similar to: Can I splice underground 12-2 UF cable run to a water pump?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also How can I repair a damaged UF cable

Buried splices can be done using special splice kits.
Splice kits for smaller gauges are readily available, but this larger wire is more specialised,  but even this size of wire is still damaged by a backhoe, so there will be splice kits to repair it. You will probably have to go somewhere that specialises in supplying parts to electricians.
